# Can I make an image from the disk starting at x address?

Tags: ram, dd, disk-image

I'm trying to get a specific data from the disk starting at specific address (don't know if it was physical address or not, ex: 0x00000000DA88FFFF, with size 0x5776). Actually I'm new with disk imager and these stuff and I found that **dd** command is suitable for making disk images, but I couldn't found anything related to start imaging from specific addresses with a specific size, is there anyway to do this? I want to extract a specific information from the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dd** has the `skip` parameter allowing you to skip a portion at the start of the input.

Thing is, dd reads a block at a time, reading a block into memory then writing that block to the output, then repeating.  If the number of bytes you want to skip is not a multiple of the default block size (512) then you'll need to set block size.  The following would work:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=1 skip=3666411519 count=22390 of=/some/file
```

In that case you're setting block size to a single byte (because your skip value is arbitrary and not a multiple of anything in particular).

Using a block size of 1 byte will be relatively slow but if you're only reading about 22kB it's not a huge problem.

Comment: it's more clear for me now, but still have some points, if I need to start dd from a specific address, how to start there? the conversion between skip and the addresses, second, if I need around 1kB, how to specify this?

Comment: The address you had beginning with 0x was in hexadecimal.  Convert to decimal with [this tool](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter).  1kB is 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`dd` has a `skip` flag:

```
skip=N skip N ibs-sized blocks at start of input
```

But the address then has to be N*ibs. But  0x00000000DA88FFFF = 3×1222137173, which doesn't seem a reasonable starting point. In general, you could do:

```
dd ibs=X start=Y count=Z if=/some/disk
```

To copy `Z*X` bytes starting from `Y*X`.

Comment: What is ibs? input bytes? and the count specify the byte number will be read? it's more clear but still have no idea how to put the address in the **start**? how to convert it? convert it to what? at this point am lost

Comment: @Aziz see manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/dd.1.html As I said, if `start=Y` and `ibs=X`, then it starts reading from bytes `Y*X`. What part of that is unclear?

Comment: start=Y (ex. Y=0x00000000DA88FFFF) , should I put it in this form? and for the ibs= 1b, just the address how to put it ??

Comment: @Aziz you haven't said what your address actually is, and you don't even know what it is or what it's supposed to mean, so how can I answer that?